# Mockito unit test for rest template

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, resttemplate

I am trying to write a unit test for rest template that is making http calls. I have created the rest template with the rest template builder, shown below. the rest template is set to configure read and connection timeouts. I also have a retry template that is to execute retries when the application has a timeout. I am at the point where I have specified the http methods: postForEntity, exchange, and getForEntity that need to retried in the retry template and need help with writing unit tests. I started with the getForEntity method but am receiving a different output from what is expected. any assistance with this would be helpful.

Rest Template

```
 @Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplateBuilder()
            .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .build();
```

}

Retrying getForEntity

```
 public ResponseEntity getForEntity(URI uri, Class c) {
    return retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
        return restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, c);
    });
}
```

Unit Test

```
public class RetryRestTemplateTest {

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Mock
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

private RetryRestTemplate retryRestTemplate;

String testUrl = "http://localhost:8080";

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    retryRestTemplate = new RetryRestTemplate(
            restTemplate,
            retryTemplate
    );
}

@Test
public void getForEntity() throws URISyntaxException{
    URI testUri= new URI(testUrl);
    ArgumentCaptor<URI> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(URI.class);

    doReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("ResponseString", HttpStatus.OK))
            .when(restTemplate).getForEntity(any(URI.class), eq(String.class));

    assertThat(restTemplate.getForEntity(testUri, String.class), is(HttpStatus.OK));

    verify(restTemplate).getForEntity(argument.capture(), eq(String.class));
    assertThat(argument.getValue().toString(), is(testUri));
}}
```

My expected should be is <200 OK> and my actual is <<200 OK OK,ResponseString,[]>>

Any help on this would be helpful as I am not that experienced with Mockito and Junit.

Comment: What are you trying to validate/test?

Comment: I am trying to test the getForEntity method

Answer (score 1):

Your expectations are not aligned with the code you wrote `getForEntity` does not return a `HttpStatus` instance, instead it returns a `ResponseEntity<String>`. Comparing a `ResponseEntity<String>` with a `HttpStatus` will never yield equal.

A fixed version of your test:

```
  @Test
  public void getForEntity() throws URISyntaxException {
    URI testUri = new URI(testUrl);
    ArgumentCaptor<URI> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(URI.class);

    doReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("ResponseString", HttpStatus.OK))
        .when(restTemplate).getForEntity(any(URI.class), eq(String.class));

    assertThat(restTemplate.getForEntity(testUri, String.class).getStatusCode(),
        CoreMatchers.is(HttpStatus.OK));

    verify(restTemplate).getForEntity(argument.capture(), eq(String.class));
    assertThat(argument.getValue(), CoreMatchers.is(testUri));
  }
```

Some side note: The test does not really test `getForEntity`, it tests that a java proxy you created with mockito does return the mocked result. Imho you are actually testing if the mock framework works...

```
doReturn(new ResponseEntity<>("ResponseString", HttpStatus.OK)).when(restTemplate).getForEntity(any(URI.class), eq(String.class));
```

As discussed in the comments, an integration test of the `RestTemplate` could be:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class RetryRestTemplateTest {

  private final MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();

  @BeforeEach
  public void setup() throws IOException {
    server.start();
  }

  @AfterEach
  public void teardown() throws IOException {
    server.close();
  }

  @Test
  public void getForEntity() {
    URI testUri = server.url("/").uri();
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200).setBody("{}"));

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    ResponseEntity<String> forEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(testUri, String.class);
    assertThat(forEntity.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK));
    assertThat(forEntity.getBody(), is("{}"));
  }
}
```

The following test dependencies are needed:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @Andreas. I am new to unit testing, can you assist with how to test for the getForEntity method, exchange method, and postForEntity methods?

Comment: This is a matter of taste, but if you want to test `postForEntity` which has the observable behaviour of doing an http call, I would just post to a real endpoint. There are various ways of building a mock endpoint. I like using https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver This would then spin up a http server in ms .